# Velocity-React Won't Load with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, animation, webpack, window, velocity.js

I am trying to use the following library https://www.npmjs.com/package/velocity-react for animations in my react/webpack project. I am getting a really weird error when I even try and include the file. I do this by, following the documentation, requiring the package at the top of my webpack.config.js file like this:

```
  require('velocity-animate');
  require('velocity-animate/velocity.ui');
```

The error I get is:

```
/Users/patientplatypus/Documents/arc-app/node_modules/velocity-animate/velocity.js:417
})(window);
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/patientplatypus/Documents/arc-app/node_modules/velocity-animate/velocity.js:417:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/patientplatypus/Documents/arc-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/patientplatypus/Documents/arc-app/webpack.config.js:5:1)
```

This is very frustrating as it looks like a very neat package, but it won't even load. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include it in your *entry point*, not the config. What you include in the config is only used for the bundling process, which is in Node not the browser, and `window` does not exist in Node.

Assuming you have the following entry configuration:

```
entry: './src/index.js'
```

In `./src/index.js` you import it:

```
require('velocity-animate');
require('velocity-animate/velocity.ui');

// Or with ES modules
import 'velocity-animate';
import 'velocity-animate/velocity.ui';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a module, you can do something like this.

```
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
```

and then use it like this.

```
let el = document.querySelector("#someId");
Velocity(el, "fadeIn", {duration: 700, stagger: 200,  easing: "easeInSine"});
```

`window` does not exist in `NodeJS`, it is related to `DOM`.